# Ubuntu 14.04 VPS - How to keep process running in background and periodically make sure that it is still running

Tags: 14.04, bash

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 VPS which is hosting one of my sites that is dynamically generated using Python's Pelican Library.  There is a "make regenerate" command I can run that will automatically check for changes to the source files and when it finds them it will automatically regenerate the HTML with the new changes.

This works great when I am logged into the VPS and allowing this processes to run in the terminal, but when I log out it stops.

What I want to do is keep this process running all the time and have something check to make sure that it is still running.  If it is not running, I want it to start.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

This question might be a better fit for [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) seeing as it's essentially about typical sysadmin jobs such as process management, rather than anything Ubuntu specific but anyway, an answer:

What you're essentially talking about is a daemon process - that is a process that's started and monitored by the operating system, and restarted on failure.

You could use a system `init` script for this, but there can be alot of subtle management issues with init scripts, and there is already a better, easier solution. I would highly recommend [supervisord](http://supervisord.org)

From that page:

> [...] It shares some of the same goals of programs like launchd, daemontools, and runit. Unlike some of these programs, it is not meant to be run as a substitute for init as “process id 1”. Instead it is meant to be used to control processes related to a project or a customer, and is meant to start like any other program at boot time.

On Ubuntu, you can install supervisord with `sudo apt-get install supervisor`.
Then create a new config file in supervisor's config directory (on Ubuntu, this is `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`) and name it something like `pelican_watcher.conf` (the `.conf` extension matters)

```
[program:pelican_watcher]
directory=/directory/of/command
command=watch_regenerate.py
user=timbram
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Then, you can create a program that simply watches for changes, and runs `make regenerate` when a file has changed (make sure you add your own real values for `user`, `command`, and `directory`, above).

This python script uses the `watchdog` package to notify you of changes to a directory, and run some command when files change.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
import subprocess
import time

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

PELICAN_DIR = "/path/to/your/pelican/site"


class PelicanWatcher(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(['make', 'regenerate'])
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            # You may want better logging here, such as sending mail or similar
            sys.stderr.write("an error occurred!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    observer = Observer()
    event_handler = PelicanWatcher()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, PELICAN_DIR, recursive=True)

    observer.start()
    # Now sleep forever while watchdog does it's business
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
```

To install watchdog, `sudo apt-get install python-watchdog`, then, make sure you edit the fake paths I've put in (`PELICAN_DIR`)

Then, put this python script wherever you specified in the supervisor configuration file (`watch_regenerate.py`), make it executable, and `sudo supervisorctl reread && sudo supervisorctl update`. From there, supervisord will restart this script if it unexpectedly terminates, and will start the process at boot.

supervisor also has an interactive command where you can inspect running processes: `sudo supervisorctl` with no arguments

readthedocs: http://super